# Executable find library in same directory

Tags: cmake

When I use `target_link_libraries` to try link in the same directory instead of put a relative path `(.)`, it means when I compile the software and run `readelf` command I see the full library like `/home/mypath/project/mylib.so`, but when I execute my program in other compile the home path change and the link is broken, so I would like that when I compile the program the relative path was put instead of the full path, someone knows to do it with CMake?

Comment: This might be best solved by installing your executable, and using the info from this question/answer to fix the "rpath" in your installed executable: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22206122/1401351